# wp_nav_menu remove class and id from li

Tags: menus, customization

I'm new to wordpress and trying to learn my way through from making a theme.
Right now I am using wp_nav_menu to generate my menu
My menu consists of pages and categories

However, the default generation of the menu looks like

```
<div id="navi">
<div class="menu-primary-container">  
  <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-16"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-15"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to remove all the class and id from li and ul. I have been googling for awhile now. Tried different methods and no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm currently using Wordpress 3.1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the [Falcon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/falcon/) plugin, it has a feature to cleanup menu item's ID & classes, but keep only essentials ones (like `current-menu-item`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in [the `wp_nav_menu()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L111), you see the items are written by [`walk_nav_menu_tree()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L462), which calls [`Walker_Nav_Menu`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L10) to do the work (unless you specified your own walker class). This class contains a method [`start_el()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L57) that is called for each menu item. In this function, you see that the classes are filtered through `nav_menu_css_class` and the id is filtered through `nav_menu_item_id`. So if you attach your own code to these hooks, you can change them to anything you want.

Submenus [are always wrapped with `<ul class="sub-menu">`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L33), the main wrapper [can be changed via the `menu_id` and `menu_class` arguments](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L206).

Answer (score 7):

You can change the id and class of each item with the `nav_menu_item_id` and `nav_menu_css_class` filter hooks like so:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'clear_nav_menu_item_id', 10, 3);
function clear_nav_menu_item_id($id, $item, $args) {
    return "";
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'clear_nav_menu_item_class', 10, 3);
function clear_nav_menu_item_class($classes, $item, $args) {
    return array();
}
```

This will result in items saying `<li id="" class="">`. The same mechanism can be used to set IDs to something useful, such as the page slug.

Comment: Always best to use core WP return functions. So in this case use: `add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', '__return_null', 10, 3 );` or `add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', '__return_empty_array', 10, 3 );`

Answer (score 1):

```
function wp_nav_menu_remove_attributes( $menu ){
    return $menu = preg_replace('/ id=\"(.*)\" class=\"(.*)\"/iU', '', $menu );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'wp_nav_menu_remove_attributes' );
```

Comment: will this prevent me from adding a "active" class for my active navigation?

Comment: Yes, because this is what u asked for.

Answer (score 1):

This solution was posted on [wp3layout](http://www.wp3layouts.com/wp/remove-every-class-id-wordpress-wp_nav_menu/) .You should add this to your theme's function.php

```
 
function remove_css_id_filter($var) {
    return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item')) : '';
} 
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'remove_css_id_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'remove_css_id_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'remove_css_id_filter', 100, 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should keep **menu-item-has-children** & **current-menu-item** for styling

*paste below code in your functions.php*

```
//remove useless CSS classes for each li item
function remove_css_from_menu($var)
{
    return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item', 'menu-item-has-children',)) : '';
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'remove_css_from_menu', 100, 1);
//remove ID for each li item
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', '__return_false');
```

Comment: inspired from previous comment of @Jan Fabry