# Custom markup with wp_nav_menu based on pages

Tags: theme-development, navigation

How might I have custom markup for my menus, like I want to give menu items something like `id="menuitem-postname"` how might I do that?

Comment: How are you creating the menu? Does it use the new custom menus in the admin, wp_list_pages or something else?

Comment: I use `wp_nav_menu()`

Comment: Just so I am clear on what you are trying to accomplish. wp_nav_menu() already gives you an id similar to menu-item-[id]. You want to change that id="menuitem-postname" correct? What do you mean by postname? It looks like you can only add pages, categories and custom links to the menu's. Do you want the slug of the page or the category? Also, the id is on the <li> tag. Are you wanting to update that id or add an id to the <a> tag? Also, you can check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12784/wp-nav-menu-remove-class-and-id-from-li to see if that is any help

Comment: @PNMG, I am trying to style my menu item. `menu-item-[id]` is not really readable as I wont know without looking at the dashboard whats `id` is refering to. So I am looking for something more intuitive like the slug (currently for a page). ID on the `<li>` is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I could think to do this would be to add a filter to `wp_nav_menu_items`. Here is the code that I got to work (just add it to your themes functions.php file):

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_id_name_nav', 10, 2);
function my_id_name_nav($items,$args) {
  if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
    preg_match_all('/<li id="menu-item-([0-9]+)"([^>]+)>\s*<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a><\/li>/i', $items, $matches);
    $newItems = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++){
      $short = explode('/', $matches[3][$i]);
      $short = $short[count($short) - 2]; // if there is no trailing slash, subtract 1 instead of 2
      array_push($newItems, '<li id="menu-item-'. $short .'"'. $matches[2][$i] .'><a href="'. $matches[3][$i] .'">'. $matches[4][$i] .'</a></li>');
    }
    return implode('', $newItems);
  } else {
    return $items;
  }
}
```

It uses the last part of the url to create the page name for the id. So menu-item-2 for http://yoursite.com/page1/page2/ would become menu-item-page2.

The `if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )` is for targeting a specific menu. If you want to do this for all menus just remove the if else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple ... Use a Custom Walker ... All you need to do is attach something constant to the id element ... such as the actual post or page id ... That's in the menu_item->object_id ... I don't really see why your doing this though ... with a cursory knowledge of CSS you can easily utilize the cascade to address an items children ... All the menu_items are already assigned css classes ... @see [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

```
$args = array (

'theme_location'  => 'primary',
'menu'            => 'Menu Name',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => 'nav',
'container_id'    => FALSE,
'menu_class'      => FALSE,
'menu_id'         => FALSE,
'echo'            => TRUE,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => FALSE,
'after'           => FALSE,
'link_before'     => FALSE,
'link_after'      => FALSE,
'items_wrap'      => "\n\t" . '<ul>%3$s</ul>' . "\n",
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => new ID_Walker()
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );

class ID_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );

            /** 
            * Add the object id as a reference
            * This will tie your menu_item id ref to your post page or cpt
            */  

    $oid = esc_attr( $item->object_id ); 

            /**
            * Append the object id to the element id  
            */

    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '-' . $oid . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a custom function to the [nav_menu_item_id hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_item_id/) that does something like this:

```
function custom_nav_menu_item_id($menu_id, $item, $args, $depth) {
    if ($item) {
        switch ($item->object) {
            case "page":
                // If the menu item's object is a page,
                // retrieve it and return its name.
                $post = get_post($item->object_id);
                return $post->post_name;

            case "category":
                // If the menu item's object is a category,
                // retrieve it and return its slug.
                $category = get_category($item->object_id);
                return $category->slug;
        }
    }

    // Return the standard menu id by default.
    return $menu_id;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'custom_nav_menu_item_id', 10, 2);
```

If there are more menu item types than `page` and `category`, it's easy to add `case` blocks for each of them.