# How can I remove Wordpress element IDs and Class names in the HTML?

Tags: widgets, id

Very much following this advice for body class: https://edinburghwp.com/removing-page-post-tag-category-taxonomy-ids-from-body_class-wordpress/

I'd like to remove the IDs and Classes that WP automatically ads to all its elements.

Someone has posted how to do this with menu items: [wp_nav_menu remove class and id from li](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12784/wp-nav-menu-remove-class-and-id-from-li)

But I can't figure out a way to do it for say, custom HTML widgets, or text widgets, which produce an ID for each one that is created or added to a site https://cloudup.com/cDOPVyozlA8 --> it seems unnecessary since other classes control these areas.

Also asked this question about the parent page IDs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335732/how-can-i-remove-parent-pageid-id-body-classes-in-wordpress

Trying to reduce all the added CSS and HTML references to help with site speed...hopefully.

Comment: When you say “all of its elements” I’d expect the bulk of your HTML to come from your templates not the core WordPress so you’ll only be making a small change to a subset of your page. And I’d be surprised if this made any significant difference to download speed or page render time. What’s the specific problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: I still think it's quite a lot of added, unnecessary class and ID names, that are based on one specific database ID at a time. I would love to remove them, even if it's just for clarity of mind while seeing what is going on on the page. I also think that with Core Web Vitals coming up, we are dealing with 'shaving' off milliseconds to get under a certain threshold, at least in the case I'm dealing with. It keeps mentioning these things and I'll like them out of the way, even if only to just see what's left. I'd absolutely be thankful for your help but I understand if this is a bother to you :)